# Server Side Ajax Datatables

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I am executing serverside datatables and im getting this kind of error

```
TypeError: c is undefined
...iRecordsDisplay=parseInt(f,10);d=0;for(e=c.length;d<e;d++)N(a,c[d]);a.aiDisplay=...
```

this is my server side,

```
require_once '../../resources/db.config.php';

    $db = DATABASE::instance();
    $mysqli = $db->get(); 

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM mst_product");
    $rows = array();
        while( $r = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
            $rows[] = $r ;
        }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and my datatables

```
<table id="productlist" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>No</th>
                              <th>SKU</th>
                              <th>Product Description</th>
                              <th>Product Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#productlist").DataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../../../html/data/productlist.php",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "prod_id" },
                { "data": "prod_sku" },
                { "data": "prod_desc" },
                { "data": "prod_prc_idr" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my imports,

```
    <!-- DATA TABLES -->
    <link href="../../library/plugins/datatables/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!-- DATATABLES -->
<script src="../../library/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../library/plugins/datatables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

please help me i dont know where i am doing wrong .... JSON data service is fine...

Comment: What does the ajax response look like? Have a look at the response using your browsers devtools. Also your sending a POST request for a GET action. Try removing the `"type": "POST"` line form the DataTable request object.

Comment: What is the respone json?